# Raster letter object to Vector, Tracing or Manual re-creation

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I need this big letter a to separate from the image and vectorize it. How do I do that in Illustrator? When I try trace image, everything disappears except few random lines. I guess I am doing something wrong, but don't know why. If anyone could advise what to do, I would really appreciate it! Thank you in advance,

Katarina[image]

Comment: Grab the Pen tool and *manually* trace the letter.

Comment: If that is indeed your source then its both faster amd less fuss to manualy trace. its just 20-30 points to place.

Comment: @Scott For novice, it will take more time than image tracing (I hope the topic starter will follow the small tute I've created for her) %)

Comment: @joojaa I can trace that shape in...15 points! (anyone remember Name That Tune?)

Comment: [I can do it in 14](http://i.stack.imgur.com/pljae.jpg) (Yup I remember). @Ilan nothing beats practice and the results of manually tracing will almost always be better than any automated method.

Comment: Well 20 was my estimate but i ended up using 14 points when i did it (I have a symmetry problem in my head :). Eventually computer trace will be as good as human. 12 should be possible tough.

Answer (score 2):

If you use **ILLUSTRATOR ONLY** It takes 1 minute:

After you "Place" the image, press on fall-down menu triangle and choose 3 colors option -

[image]

You get this -

[image]

Now, ungroup (select the layer and choose Object->Ungroup) and delete all the objects leaving only the ugly "a" - you select this ugly compound "a" and choose Select->Inverse and press Delete:

[image]

Results in -

[image]

Now, you select the ugly "a", press "-" -

[image]

And now you click on all the points which make you "a" ugly - this will delete them and smooth the path. As a final step you press "a" and adjust the remaining anchor points:

[image]

the same result without selection:

[image]

You should be able to finish this tute in less than 5 minutes (if not - exercise until you do).

Comment: She can simply trace the final "a" you provided :)

Comment: @go-me I hope she will learn something as well %)

Comment: @llann I'm sure she will; I did!

Comment: @llian Here, done, thanks! http://i.imgur.com/GgILQ1t.jpg

Comment: Its till got things to fix like the join, when i tested to manually trace it took 3 minutes so by no means a super win for tracing considering the errors. But nice enough i suppose.

Comment: This is a good walkthrough, but my point was.. spend 5 minutes tracing and fixing.... or 2 minutes just manually recreating. And you generally get better results manually for simple things like this.

Comment: Feels like a GD:SE Inception scenario: You saved 3 minutes of your life, spend it on GD:SE and mention for XX minutes how you saved 3 minutes! Some people don't like manually tracing everything, and I'm one of them. Llan suggested an extra trick other than tracing, that's good.

Comment: @scott what about object with 1000 points ;))

Comment: I did post "simple stuff like this" Ilan :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to copy the image into Photoshop and adjust brightness -150. Then copy this image to Illustrator and live trace it with Simple trace.  You might need to tweek the curve a little bit to get the right shape, but it's 90% of work done.
Regards,Goran

Answer (score 0):

Delete the text outside the "a" letter. It goes very fast with the selection tool like the polygonal lasso.

[image: Erase sides with polygonal lasso]

Then go in the menu "image", then "Adjustment" and then select "levels".

Select the black color picker on the right, and go pick the light gray color of your "a". All the graphic will turn black.

Then import this in Illustrator and use the automatic image trace. Adjust the settings as you prefer.